# Using PostFix address rewriting to entirely remove a recipient from an outgoing email in a relay

Tags: postfix

I am trying to use postfix to entirely remove a particular recipient entirely from the "to" or "cc" fields of an email, but have not figure out how to do so yet.

I have postfix configured as a relay host. I am using it to relay from Exchange on Office 365 to `smtp.gmail.com`. This is to allow a specific user to send from their Office 365 account out of their old `gmail.com` email address. We have an outbound connector in Exchange set up to route to the postfix relay server, and a rule set to send this user's outbound mail to the connector.

The postfix relay is then set up to use normal SMTP AUTH to relay mail to `smtp.gmail.com`.

This all works perfectly. Say the user's gmail is `user@gmail.com` and their exchange mailbox is `user@domain.com`. To send their 'user@gmail.com' mail to their Office 365 account, we have a simple forwarder set up in gmail to forward all mail to user@`domain.com`.

The one issue we're trying to improve, is if the user replies all to any of the forwarded mail in the exchange inbox using Outlook, their `user@gmail.com` address will show up as a "To" recipient. Because the original mail was sent to their `user@gmail address`, and that mail was then forwarded to `user@domain.com`, Outlook connect to `user@domain.com` thinks their gmail address is another user to be replied to. I don't know any way to stop Outlook from doing this.

To keep them from continually mailing themselves, we just want to use a simple rule in the postfix relay to remove themselves from the "To" (or "CC") fields. I've set up a canonical rule on recipients in main.cf:

`recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical`

And then I'm trying to get the canonical ap to replace `user@gmail.com` with.... something that will delete it entirely out of the email's recipients.

I can get the desired rewrite to match `user@gmail.com` in the To field, but I cannot for the life of me figure out a hash or regexp rule (if I switch to regex mapping) that will *remove* the email address entirely. I've tried a blank, which postmap (when I try to create a db) complains is not a valid `key whitespace value` entry. Anyone have any luck using rules to entirely remove a particular recipient from an email?

Please note I cross-posted this on reddit as well because I cannot find anything related to removal (instead of just rewriting) recipients anywhere: `https://www.reddit.com/r/postfix/comments/128plg8/using_postfix_address_rewriting_to_entirely/`

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, my solution was to create an after-queue content filter to be called to remove the `user@gmail.com` address from both the recipients for the message as well as from the "To:" and "Cc:" email headers in the message. The former is required so that we don't send an actual email to `user@gmail.com`, and the latter is just so `user@gmail.com` doesn't show up in those headers when the email arrives at the recipients.

Content added to master.cf:

```
myhook unix - n n - - pipe
  flags=F user=filter argv=/etc/postfix/mail-cleaner/mail-cleaner.php ${sender} ${size} ${recipient}

smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
        -o content_filter=myhook:dummy
```

And mail-cleaner.php, which uses the ZBateson MailMimeParser to cleanly modify the email headers.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use ZBateson\MailMimeParser\MailMimeParser;
use ZBateson\MailMimeParser\Message;
use ZBateson\MailMimeParser\Header\Part\HeaderPartFactory;
use ZBateson\MailMimeParser\Header\Part\MimeLiteralPartFactory;
use ZBateson\MailMimeParser\Header\HeaderFactory;
use ZBateson\MailMimeParser\Header\AddressHeader;
use ZBateson\MailMimeParser\Header\Consumer\ConsumerService;
use ZBateson\MbWrapper\MbWrapper;

$removeAddresses = ["useruser@gmail.com", "user.user@gmail.com"];

$fileOut = fopen("/tmp/postfix/postfixtest-".date("Y-m-d"), "a");

fwrite($fileOut, "==============================================\n");
fwrite($fileOut, "New running at ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n");
fwrite($fileOut, "Receipients to remove: ".implode(",",$removeAddresses)."\n");

// Print the command line argument
for ($i = 1; $i < count($argv); $i++) {
    fwrite($fileOut, "  Arg $i: " . $argv[$i] . "\n");
}

// Get receipients
$args = $argv; // Copy all command line arguments to $args array
$from = $argv[1];

array_shift($args); // Remove first argument which is the script name
array_shift($args); // Remove second argument
$recepients = array_slice($args, 1); // Copy the third and all the rest of command line arguments into $result array

fwrite($fileOut, "From: ".$from."\nReceipients: ".implode(",",$recepients)."\n");

// Remove receipients
foreach ($recepients as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($removeAddresses as $remove) {
        if (strpos($value, $remove) !== false) {
            fwrite($fileOut, "    Removing: ".$recepients[$key]."\n");
            unset($recepients[$key]);
        }
    }
}

fwrite($fileOut, " -> New recipients: ".implode(",",$recepients)."\n");

// Read the email from stdin
$email = stream_get_contents(STDIN);

// Parse the email using MailMimeParser
$parser = new MailMimeParser();
$message = $parser->parse($email, true);

fwrite($fileOut,"Message-ID: ".$message->getHeader("Message-ID")->getRawValue()."\nSubject: ".$message->getHeader("Subject")->getRawValue()."\n");

$mbWrapper = new MbWrapper();
$headerPartFactory = new HeaderPartFactory($mbWrapper);
$mimeLiteralPartFactory = new MimeLiteralPartFactory($mbWrapper);

$consumerService = new ConsumerService($headerPartFactory, $mimeLiteralPartFactory);

$headerFactory = new HeaderFactory($consumerService, $mimeLiteralPartFactory);

// Get the "To" header
removeAddress($consumerService, $message, "To", $removeAddresses, $fileOut);
removeAddress($consumerService, $message, "Cc", $removeAddresses, $fileOut);

// Send the modified email using sendmail
$sendmailPath = '/usr/sbin/sendmail'; // or wherever your sendmail binary is located
$sendmailArgs = '-G -i '.implode(' ',$recepients);

fwrite($fileOut,"Calling Sendmail: ".$sendmailPath." ".$sendmailArgs."\n");

$process = proc_open("$sendmailPath $sendmailArgs", [
    0 => ['pipe', 'r'], // stdin
    1 => ['pipe', 'w'], // stdout
    2 => ['pipe', 'w'], // stderr
], $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    $message->save($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $exitCode = proc_close($process);
    if ($exitCode !== 0) {
        $err = "ERROR: Sendmail failed with exit code $exitCode:\n$stdout\n$stderr";
        fwrite($fileOut,$err."\n");
        throw new Exception($err);
    }
} else {
    $err = "Failed to start sendmail process";
    fwrite($fileOut,$err."\n");
    throw new Exception($err);
}

fwrite($fileOut,"-> Success\n");
fclose($fileOut);

exit(0);

// Function to remove values from header
function removeAddress($consumerService, $message, $fieldName, $removeAddresses, $fileOut) { 
    $header = $message->getHeader($fieldName);

    if ($header === null) {
        fwrite($fileOut,$fieldName ." is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    
    if ($header instanceof AddressHeader) {
        $addresses = $header->getAddresses();
        
        fwrite($fileOut, $fieldName.": ".implode(",", $addresses)."\n");
        
        foreach ($addresses as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($removeAddresses as $remove) {
                if (strpos($value, $remove) !== false) {
                    fwrite($fileOut, "    Removing: ".$addresses[$key]."\n");
                    unset($addresses[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        
        $message->removeHeader($fieldName);

        if (count($addresses) > 0) {
            $newHeader = new AddressHeader($consumerService,$fieldName,implode(",",$addresses));
            $message->setRawHeader($fieldName, $newHeader->getRawValue());
            fwrite($fileOut, " -> New ".$fieldName.": ".$message->getHeader($fieldName)->getRawValue()."\n");
        }
        else {
            fwrite($fileOut, " -> ".$fieldName." is now empty\n");
        }
        
        return;
    }
    throw new Exception($fieldName." header invalid");
}

?>
```